# Using OCL for Date attributes

Tags: eclipse, emf, ocl, ecore

I have some models with date attributes and I want to include ocl for validation and derivation.

Searching on the internet I found some articles and papers referring to `date.isBefore(date)` or `date.before(date)` methods but these methods are not recognized in OCL.

Additionally I would like to define derivation such as `derivation: endDate + 10;`.

Do I have to redefine a Date class with all methods I need ?

Any material or link related to it is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Given that OCL does not define `Date`, the authors' should have gone the long way round in order to formally define `isBefore` (and pages are a scarce resource in academic writing ;)

> A few “primitive types” including numbers and strings are predefined
>   in UML [RJB98*, p. 394]. The availability of other types like date and
>   money is “system-dependent”. In any case, the semantics of primitive
>   types has to be defined outside UML.
>   (Richters Mark. [A Precise Approach to Validating UML Models and OCL Constraints](http://www.db.informatik.uni-bremen.de/teaching/courses/ss2002_oose/m.pdf), Universität Bremen, p. 33, 86)

<sub>[RJB98] Rumbaugh, Jacobson, and Booch. The Unified Modeling
Language Reference Manual. Addison-Wesley, 1998.</sub>

While I'm not proficient in EMF, According to [this link](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/121515/) any Java datatype can be used in your models by declaring it as 
the instance type of an EDataType for your Ecore model. (See also [this reference](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.ocl.doc%2Freferences%2Foverview%2Fadvanced%2Fcustomization.html))

Comment: I came across these references already but it does not make things clear. Although I have declared new `EDataType` using `java.util.Date`, within OCL, operations such as `>=`, `<` or methods like `data.before(old_data)` are not recognized. Anyway, I really appreciate your help.